Will removing these walls impact structural integrity?
I'd like to remove these two walls (indicated by red circles on the first image) to open up the master bath. I don't believe that they are structural, however just looking for feedback prior to cutting them out.
Neither of these walls lineup with any of the beams shown in the second image, but they are perpendicular to the floor joists.
Am I clear to remove?



quick look says those are not structural just cosmetic

99.9% chance they're nonstructural.

As these walls have no foundation under them, that means they are supported only by the floor joists, and so  they are almost certainly not structural. so deleting them will not signiifcanlty impact you houses structural integrity.
